# Background Process subprocess.Popen with Pipe

Tags: python, background, subprocess, audio-recording

I'm trying to record and convert a stream with python using arecord.

In the shell this is a command more or less like:

```
arecord -B 5000 -f dat | lame -m j -q 5 -V 2 - test.mp3 &
```

In Python I tried this with subprocess.Popen:

```
reccmd = ["arecord", "-B", "5000", "-f", "dat"]
mp3cmd = ["lame", "-m", "j", "-q", "5", "-V", "2", "-", "test.mp3"]
p = subprocess.Popen(reccmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(mp3cmd, stdin=p.stdout)
p2.communicate()
```

But I don't know how to include the "&" or something similar in the code to be able to stop the recording with a

`killall arecord` command

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want the main Python process to block while executing the subprocesses, simply don't call `p2.communicate()`.  The calls to `subprocess.Popen()` don't block.

Comment: Thank you very much. Wasted hours trying to find a way out and sometimes the answer is just this easy